# Predicted probabilities in R

Tags: r, probability, logistic-regression

I have a logit model with a dummy variable and I'd like to plot the predicted variables at renting=0 and renting=1. I get an error message after creating the `cex2` object that says:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev =          object$xlevels) : variable lengths differ (found for 'clt2')
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 100 rows but variables found have 4139 rows
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
model1<-glm(adaycare~fincbtax+I(fincbtax^2)+clt2+clt6+got6+bot6+renting,    family="binomial")
summary(model1)

exp(coef(model1))

#predicted values

newcex <-with(cex,data.frame(fincbtax=mean(fincbtax),clt2=mean(clt2),clt6=mean(clt6),got6=mean(got6),bot6=mean(bot6),renting=(1:0)))
newcex$rentingProb<-predict(model1,newdata=newcex,type="response")

cex2<-with(cex,data.frame(fincbtax=rep(seq(from=10000,to=500000,length.out=50),2),renting=(rep(0:1,each=50))))

cex3<-cbind(cex2,predict(model1,cex2,type="link",se=TRUE))

cex3 <- within(cex2, {
  PredictedProb <- plogis(fit)
  LL <- plogis(model1 - (1.96 * se.fit))
  UL <- plogis(fit + (1.96 * se.fit))
})
```

Comment: Exactly which step causes the error?  My bet is that the error is from trying to use `cex2` in `predict`.  The data.frame `cex2` should have all the explanatory variables in it if you want to use it in `predict`.  If you want to set some values to their mean, you can do so much like you did with `newcex` and R will recycle them to the appropriate length.

Comment: Thanks for your response aosmith. The error occurs at the line `cex2<-...` I am trying to assign certain values to the income valuable `fincbtax` ranging from 10000-500000 at both `renting` values of 0 and 1.

Comment: Try just assinging `cex2` to `data.frame(fincbtax=rep(seq(from=10000,to=500000,length.out=50),2),renting=(rep(0:1,each=50)))`, then (but my first comment about needing all the explanatory variables in `cex2` still holds, though).